# Making animations like those on apple web site

Tags: jquery, animation, transition

I want to make animations like those on apple web site:

http://www.apple.com/iphone/

or if above link is not working http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05WEIWZvw2Q

Is there some productive framework (eg jquery plugin) dedicated to this kind of job?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is animate an image on a path. Jquery does this nicely:

[Jquery.Path](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path)

[Examples](http://weepy.github.com/jquery.path/)

Answer (score 3):

try this one http://www.sequencejs.com/

apple style demo: http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/apple-style/

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is four years old...
But if someone else is searching for a solution...

Try Adobe Edge Animate
With Adobe Muse you can generate wonderful animations.

Answer (score -1):

Apple is well-known for the sleek animations on their product pages. For example, as you scroll down the page products may slide into view, MacBooks fold open and iPhones spin, all while showing off the hardware, demonstrating the software and telling interactive stories of how the products are used.

link -- https://css-tricks.com/lets-make-one-of-those-fancy-scrolling-animations-used-on-apple-product-pages/

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."  See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)